# Symfony 2 MenuBundle tutorial

Tags: symfony

I am looking at using this module: https://github.com/symfony-cmf/MenuBundle

I am pretty new to the Symfony framework, I want to use it as a standalone bundle outside of CMF which it is a part of.

Does anyone have a good tutorial on how to use this bundle in a standard Symfony install?
I have looked at the documentation but I seem to be missing out to use this as part of the install.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That bundle is an extended version of the [KnpMenuBundle](http://knpbundles.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle). I think you should use that bundle in you non-CMF applications. There is a lot of documentation about that bundle, which you can find [on github](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).